# Node wrangler not appearing even when enabled in User Preferences

Tags: node-editor, add-on, customization

Screenshot here:
[image: Screenshot]

Here you can see:

- Node Wrangler is enabled
- Node Wrangler is not appearing in the panel
- I'm using v2.77

How can I fix this?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Haven't tried that, but it seems that in this version, the node wrangler simply appears in a different place (just posted an answer about it). If I encounter any more issues, I'll try your suggestion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like in this version, it's simply in the left-hand panel rather than the right-hand one (not sure what their proper names are):

[image]

Comment: The left is the 'Tool shelf' and the right is generally referred to as the 'Properties' of that space (sometimes referred to as the Properties Region).

Answer (score 0):

You have to have the shader editor open as a main window then it appears in the drop menu on the right of that screen. It will not show up in any other editor i dont think so the viewport no.

Comment: The person IS in the shader editor. And as the other answer says, it's different for that version.